# Excel sheet: Copy data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am not able to copy data from one workbook to another. But with in same workbook its working. After running the macro program the destination worksheet is empty. I have 2 codes. Both are not working. My source file is **.xlsx** format and destination file is **.xlsm** format. Is there any mistakes?

**Code1:**

```
Sub mycode()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="source_file"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
Selection.Copy


Workbooks.Open Filename:="destination_file"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

**Code 2**

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("source file")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("destination file")

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

x.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are writing below *Code1* and *Code2* excel macros in a separate file, say `copy_paste.xlsm`:

**Code 1** is working when you provide a full path of files to [Workbooks.open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx):

```
Sub mycode()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\source_file.xlsx"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\destination_file.xlsm"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues               'xlPasteAll to paste everything
ActiveWorkbook.Save

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True             'to close the file
Workbooks("source_file").Close SaveChanges:=False  'to close the file

End Sub
```

To paste everything (formulas + values + formats), use paste type as [`xlPasteAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx).

**Code 2** is working too, all you need is to provide full path and you are missing `_` in file names:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\source_file.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\destination_file.xlsm")

'it copies only Range("A1") i.e. single cell
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

x.Close SaveChanges:=False
y.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I gave the full path only, for reference I mentioned source file. I tried your code, its not working. While debugging after opening the 2nd file the debugger is not getting into the next line instead its stopping the debugging itself

Comment: And 2nd file is a Macro enabled file, so is there any macro in this file which runs when you manually open it?

Comment: its not showing any error message. The code is working fine but when I open the destination file nothing is copied in that. Debugger is not showing any error message . It is abruptly stopped working when it reaches the Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\destination_file"

Comment: It seems to be some issue within your files. File sizes? Is 2nd file a blank macro enabled file? I guess there are some macros in 2nd file which causes your issue, you should check those macros once.

Comment: Its macro enabled file. There is no other macro other than this

Answer (score 1):

**edited** to add a (minimum) file check

you must specify full file path, name and extension

more over you can open only destination file, like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo2()
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim sourcePath As String, sourceFile As String, destFullPath As String '<--| not necessary, but useful not to clutter statements

    sourcePath = "C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\" '<--| specify your source file path down to the last backslash and with no source file name
    sourceFile = "source_file.xlsx" '<--| specify your source file name only, with its extension
    destFullPath = "C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Excel-Problem\destination_file.xlsm" '<--| specify your destination file FULL path

    If Dir(destFullPath) = "" Then '<--| check is such a file actually exists
        MsgBox "File " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & destFullPath & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "is not there!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The macro stops!", vbCritical
    Else
        Set y = Workbooks.Open(destFullPath)

        With y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
            .Formula = "='" & sourcePath & "[" & sourceFile & "]Sheet1'!$A$1"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        y.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

you could even open neither of them using Excel4macro

Comment: Edited to add a file check. Do you have any `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo` statements?